# Modeling data flow in a software system

Tags: software-development, data-visualization, modeling

I'm looking for a tool that will help me model data flow of an application.

In the example below I would want to click on for example *Temp 1*, and the paths to both outputs would be highlighted.

[image]

A tool like this would be useful for understanding and testing a software system with a lot of input and output parameters.

Comment: You want to just draw/record the dataflow, or you want to *extract* it from real code?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to draw it.

Comment: You appear to looking for a way to *trace* where dataflows go, too, or PowerPoint would work.

Comment: Are you looking for open source software? I mean free or commercial?

Comment: Free would be nice, but if you know of any good commercial ones I would like to hear about them.